# Problems accessing the color value defined in the tailwind.config.js file (in scss file)

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, scss-mixins, tailwind-3

in a project with Tailwind i need to darken a color defined in the tailwind.config.js (directly in the scss file).

```
@debug "Darken Color: #{darken(theme("colors.gray.500"), 10%)}";
```

This cause the error:

```
SassError: $color: theme("colors.gray.500") is not a color.
```

However when i use the notation "theme("colors.gray.500")" as value and not as a parameter of the darken function it works properly.

Can you explain me what I'm wrong and how to get the color value defined in the configuration file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because SASS handled first. Usual order to handle styles is `sass-loader -> postcss->loader -> css-loader`. Tailwind is handled by PostCSS therefore SASS does know nothing about `theme()` directive

And I found [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-sass-less-or-stylus) in documentation

> The most important thing to understand about using Tailwind with a preprocessor is that preprocessors like Sass, Less, and Stylus run separately, before Tailwind. This means that you can’t feed output from Tailwind’s theme() function into a Sass color function for example, because the theme() function isn’t actually evaluated until your Sass has been compiled to CSS and fed into PostCSS.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: @sanjarcode Register second color in Tailwind config if it fits your needs. PostCSS functions are not available in SCSS color functions because of priority (but you still may use `theme()` in .s(c|a)ss files, but not within SCSS functions like here). Same valid for CSS-variables, so this is not a solution either (darken(var(--color), 10%)) will fail)